# Returning make_shared<Base>, inheritence and casting to Derived not working as expected?

Tags: c++, c++17, shared-ptr, make-shared

Consider this example constructing `shared_ptr<T>` in various ways and returning:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class Base
{
public:
    virtual ~Base() {}
    Base(int y) : y_(y) {}
    int y_;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    Derived(int y, int z) : Base(y), z_(z) {}
    int z_;
};

std::shared_ptr<Base> A()
{
    return std::shared_ptr<Base>(new Derived(1, 2));
}

std::shared_ptr<Base> B()
{
    std::shared_ptr<Derived> result = std::make_shared<Derived>(Derived(1, 2));
    return result;
}

std::shared_ptr<Base> C()
{
    std::shared_ptr<Base> result = std::make_shared<Base>(Derived(1, 2));
    return result;
}

std::shared_ptr<Base> D()
{
    return std::make_shared<Base>(Derived(1, 2));
}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // Works fine...
    std::shared_ptr<Derived> resultA = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Derived>(A());
    
    // Works fine...
    std::shared_ptr<Derived> resultB = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Derived>(B());
    
    // Does not cast to base? ...
    std::shared_ptr<Derived> resultC = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Derived>(C());

    // Object returns fine (of type Base), but cannot be cast to Derived?
    std::shared_ptr<Base> resultCBase = C();
    std::shared_ptr<Derived> resultCDerived = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Derived>(resultCBase);
    
    // Does not cast to derived...
    std::shared_ptr<Derived> resultD = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Derived>(D());

    return 0;
}
```

In summary:

Returning `std::make_shared<T>` seems to work fine and allows caller to correctly cast. (see `A()`).

Using `make_shared<Derived>` to create a Derived, and then relying on implicit casting to return a `shared_ptr<Base>` works and allows caller to correctly cast. (see `B()`).

However for `C()` and `D()` when using `make_shared<Base>(Derived(...))`, `shared_ptr<Base>` is constructed (seems correct) but cannot cast to `std::shared_ptr<Derived>`?

I'm not familiar with what `make_shared<T>` gives (Although other answers of SO allude to better type safety and single allocation?), however it doesn't seem to perform or behave in the same manner as when replacing with `std::shared_ptr<T>(new T(...))`?

Could someone please explain to me what is happening here and why it does not work as I expect (I presume I am using it wrong, or there is some subtle behaviour trait that I should know when using it)?

Since the above example has discrepancies, `A()` & `B()` working, but not `C()` and `D()` (assuming I am using it correctly)... why is `make_shared<T>` recommended over `std::shared_ptr<T>(new T(...))`, and are there any exceptions which would mean it is not recommended over the other?

Comment: Related : [what is object slicing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'm not familiar with what `make_shared<T>` gives

It creates a `T` (on the heap, wrapping it in a `shared_ptr`). It creates exactly and *only* `T`. Your `make_shared<Base>` calls are equivalent to `new Base(Derived(1, 2)`. This will construct a `Base` (by copying from the given `Derived`'s `Base` subobject, commonly called "slicing", since you're only copying part of an object), because that's the type you gave it.

There is no `Derived` in those `shared_ptr`s, so you cannot `dynamic_pointer_cast` to that type.

> however it doesn't seem to perform or behave in the same manner as when replacing with `std::shared_ptr<T>(new T(...))`

> why is `make_shared<T>` recommended over `std::shared_ptr<T>(new T(...))`,

`std::shared_ptr<Base>(new Base(Derived(1, 2)))` would have had the exact same problem. This has nothing to do with `make_shared` and everything to do with you creating the wrong type.

Comment: Ah ok, yes that makes sense. Thank you.